# Conditional validation in Yup not working

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Given a yup schema

```
const validationSchemas = Yup.object().shape({
mobileLast4Enabled: Yup.array(), //checkbox
mobileLast4: Yup.string() //textbox
    .when('mobileLast4Enabled', {
        is: ['on'],
        then: schema => schema.required(requiredText).min(4, '4 numbers required').max(4),
        otherwise: schema => schema.notRequired()
    }),
customQuestion: Yup.string().required(requiredText),
});
```

When I do `validationSchemas.fields.mobileLast4.describe()` I get back an object that has a field `tests` which is an array describing the schema rules as expected. This works fine in the case of `customQuestion`, but when I use `.when` such as in the case of `mobileLast4` the `tests` property is an empty array. I've tried every permutation possible and it appears that my schema is correct based on other questions I've looked at.

```
const initialValues = {
mobileLast4: '',
mobileLast4Enabled: [],
customQuestion: '',
};

<Formik validationSchema={validationSchemas} initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={() => { }}> ...
```

Also, using TypeScript FWIW.

What am I doing wrong?